# How to change the text of automatic E-Mails e.g. after changing your password? (German localization)

Tags: email

How can I change the text of E-Mails that are sent automatically after creating an account/changing your password etc.? I am using Wordpress in german. So far I found the

- de_DE.mo and
- de_DE.po
  files in the folder /wp-content/languages. While the .mo-file contains some unreadable characters, I could open .po-file using Notepad++ and found:

> "Hey ###USERNAME###,\n""\n"
>
> "diese Nachricht bestätigt die Änderung deines Passworts auf  ###SITENAME###.\n"
>
> "\n"
>
> "Wenn du keine Änderung vorgenommen hast, kontaktiere bitte den
> Administrator der Website über\n"
>
> "###ADMIN_EMAIL###.\n"
>
> "\n"
>
> "Diese E-Mail wurde an ###EMAIL### gesendet.\n"
>
> "\n"
>
> "Viele Grüße\n"
>
> "von allen auf ###SITENAME###\n"
>
> "###SITEURL###"

This is the message one gets when you change the password. I then installed Wordpress on a fresh domain, changed the text in this file, but it didn't have any effect.

After trying that, I found the same text in the .mo-file. When I changed the "Hey" (the very first word) to "Hallo", it did change the E-Mail, but not only in the way that I hoped:

the first word in the text was now "Hallo" instead of "Hey", but the subject of the Mail got changed to "t" whereas and at the very bottom it now reads "###SITEURL#" instead of showing the actual URL.

Is this still the correct way to change those texts or can it be achieved easier?

Edit: I also asked this question on [wpde.org](http://forum.wpde.org/konfiguration/165958-automatische-e-mails-passwort-geaendert-etc-anpassen.html) where I was told to look for "Email Template"-Plugins. I tested these four:

- https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/email-templates/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/well-handled/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-template/

  While I could change the style of the Emails and add a logo as well as some footer content, I couldn't change the actual content of the Emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to manually edit the language files using [Poedit](https://poedit.net/). You simply download the .po-file, open it with the editor and you can see and edit all the messages created by Wordpress, be it in an Email, a popup window...
The editor can then create a new mo.-files. The .po- and .mo-file then get uploaded (overwriting the existing files) and everything should be fine.

I guess you'll have to the same process again after you intall a WP upgrade and I don't know if you can simply use the already modified file for the new WP version. But for now this works fine.